# Which would be a better approach for Multiclass segmentation?

Tags: neural-networks, image-segmentation

I would like to perform multiclass segmentation on DRR(digitally reconstructed radiographs) by using Unet network. For binary segmentation, unet works well (dice score over 0.93)
What I’m trying to do is multiclass segmentation to segment multiple bones.I looked the topic up on Kaggle and different sources, but those bear disappointing segmentation results.
I thought of ideas to start with:

1. **For each bone label, assign different Unet models to detect it.**
2. **Use ensemble models consisting of multiple networks and when classifying a pixel, use majority voting method.**
3. **Use only one model to segment multiple labels.**

Among those ideas, which would be the best approach to do multiclass segmentation? I would appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: the original paper of unet aimed to solve this types of problems... maybe worth checking it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would typically be an ensemble (2) of multi-class segmentation models (3).
However, the best next step would be to just see how well a multi-class model (i.e. using softmax) works before jumping into ensembles.

The main reason why you want to have one model to predict multiple classes rather than multiple models that each predict one class, is that the features that you need for one class will probably be better than the features for other classes.
This means that the learned features will generally be stronger and you do not need to learn the features for each class separately.

Once you have one or more multi-class models, you can typically squeeze out slightly more performance by training an ensemble of these models.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I guess I will try multiple models and make an ensemble model out of them.

Comment: @Cork if this answer actually solves your problem, you can upvote it and/or accept it. If not, you can let me know what aspect(s) of your question I missed or did not answer clearly enough.